# How to align thumbnails in center in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a small website using `bootstrap` and `angular.js` and stuck in thumbnails alignment. I am having three thumbnail and I want them centrally aligned. I have tried so many css properties but didn't get through it. Please help me out.Here is my code

```
<div ng-controller = "ModuleController as module">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center" ng-repeat="i in module.item" ng-hide="module.item.soldOut">
      <img class="img img-responsive center-block" ng-src="{{i.images[0]}}" /><br>
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in i.images">
          <a href=""><img ng-src="{{image}}"/></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span> <b>{{i.name}}</b> </span><br>
      <span> <b>{{i.price | currency : '&#8377;' }}</b> </span><br>
      <span> <b>{{i.description}} </span></b> <br><br>
      <span> <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="i.canPurchase">Add to Cart</button> </span>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here, is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rajatgarg/vgknhc6f/1/

[image]

Comment: Can u provide a fiddle?

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have the class `"pull-left"` on the thumbnail image in the html.  Should be centered after you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap's helper class: `center-block`.

I wrapped the images in a `div` - like below which seems to do the trick:

```
<div class="center-block">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[See Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes) - Running Demo below...

```css
.col-md-4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
    <img class="img img-responsive center-block" src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/" />
    <div class="row">
      <br>
      <div class="center-block">
        <a href="#" class="">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span> <b>name</b> </span>
    <br>
    <span> <b>currency</b> </span>
    <br>
    <span> <b>description</b> </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span> <button class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not working, It seems to work here but not on my machine.

Comment: @user3520629 then you would need to add more code to your question to replicate the issue (remove all the ng stuff, keep it as simple as possible).  There could be many other things influencing the alignment

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns have a default padding and floating and that why the columns aligned left. If you want to centered the div you have to remove your float like this

```
float:none; margin:0 auto;
```

Thanks

Comment: just try this..if you cant work this. i'll give you a dummy html